docker-compose : "container exited with exit code 0" on Raspberry PI
For a student project i need to run a webapp on a Raspberry PI 4B. I have that docker-compose.yml file that creates 3 containers :

web-iot (frontend)
backend (obviously backend)
postgres-db (database)

The compose file runs perfectly on my personal computer, however when I run the compose script on my Raspberry PI the db and the backend start and runs while the frontend container starts and stops after the initialisation with the message 'web-iot exited with code 0'.
Here is the docker-compose.yml file content :
services:
  web:
    image: node:20
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "cd /app; npm install; npm run dev"]
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: web-iot
    volumes:
      - ./webapp:/app

  backend:
    image: node:20
    container_name: backend
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "cd app; npm install; npm start"]
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db

  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:16
    container_name: postgres-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Here are the logs of the docker-compose up command :
Starting postgres-db ... done
Starting web-iot     ... done
Starting backend     ... done
Attaching to web-iot, postgres-db, backend
postgres-db    | 
postgres-db    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres-db    | 
postgres-db    | 2024-12-17 16:16:12.430 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.6 (Debian 16.6-1.pgdg120+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgres-db    | 2024-12-17 16:16:12.436 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres-db    | 2024-12-17 16:16:12.436 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres-db    | 2024-12-17 16:16:12.490 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-db    | 2024-12-17 16:16:12.573 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-12-17 16:14:20 UTC
postgres-db    | 2024-12-17 16:16:12.732 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web-iot        | 
web-iot        | up to date, audited 650 packages in 10s
web-iot        | 
web-iot        | 140 packages are looking for funding
web-iot        |   run `npm fund` for details
web-iot        | 
web-iot        | 2 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 1 high)
web-iot        | 
web-iot        | To address all issues, run:
web-iot        |   npm audit fix
web-iot        | 
web-iot        | Run `npm audit` for details.
web-iot        | 
web-iot        | > webapp@0.1.0 dev
web-iot        | > next dev
web-iot        | 
backend        | 
backend        | up to date, audited 812 packages in 13s
backend        | 
backend        | 120 packages are looking for funding
backend        |   run `npm fund` for details
backend        | 
backend        | 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
backend        | 
backend        | To address all issues, run:
backend        |   npm audit fix
backend        | 
backend        | Run `npm audit` for details.
backend        | 
backend        | > backend@0.0.1 prestart
backend        | > npm run rebuild
backend        | 
backend        | 
backend        | > backend@0.0.1 rebuild
backend        | > npm run clean && npm run build
backend        | 
web-iot        |   ▲ Next.js 14.2.15
web-iot        |   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
web-iot        |   - Environments: .env.local, .env
web-iot        | 
web-iot        |  ✓ Starting...
backend        | 
backend        | > backend@0.0.1 clean
backend        | > lb-clean dist *.tsbuildinfo .eslintcache
backend        | 
backend        | 
backend        | > backend@0.0.1 build
backend        | > lb-tsc
backend        | 
web-iot exited with code 0
backend        | 
backend        | > backend@0.0.1 start
backend        | > node -r source-map-support/register dist/index.js
backend        | 
backend        | WARNING: relational database doesn't support {strict: false} mode. {strict: true} mode will be set for model Table instead.
backend        | WARNING: relational database doesn't support {strict: false} mode. {strict: true} mode will be set for model Command instead.
backend        | WARNING: relational database doesn't support {strict: false} mode. {strict: true} mode will be set for model Beer instead.
backend        | Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:3000
backend        | Try http://127.0.0.1:3000/ping
postgres-db    | 2024-12-17 16:21:12.641 UTC [28] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
postgres-db    | 2024-12-17 16:21:12.710 UTC [28] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.013 s, sync=0.008 s, total=0.069 s; sync files=2, longest=0.005 s, average=0.004 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/19A71A0, redo lsn=0/19A7168

I'm pretty familiar with the concepts of docker and containers but I don't have enough knowledge about Raspberry PI and docker's limitations to truly understand the issue I'm encountering.
PS : I really need to use that docker-compose.yml file to enable me to pull the app's repository and start the app on the PI's startup.

I suspect that the pi is just slower than your laptop and the backend container is timing out before the database is accepting connections. See about adding a health-check or a dumb timeout perhaps.
